# Are there other Windows PE autorun locations apart from startnet.cmd?

Tags: windows-pe, usb-boot

I'm trying to add some commands to a PE Windows that is booted from USB.

I found this: [Windows PE autorun scripts](https://serverfault.com/questions/85579/windows-pe-autorun-scripts/1066573#1066573), saying that the "autoexec.bat" equivalent can be found here:

```
\Windows\System32\startnet.cmd
```

When I add commands to startnet.cmd, they are however not executed.

I have also searched the Registry of this PE system, but it doesn't have any of the [typical autorun entries](https://www.ghacks.net/2016/06/04/windows-automatic-startup-locations/) either.

Also, there is no Startup folder, at least not at:

```
Users\[Username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Are there other locations for autostart activity in a PE windows?

Answer (score 0):

OK so I found two more Autostart locations [here](https://systemscenter.ru/waik.en/html/4ea3d2a0-3f0a-4a41-9f93-6f06882d14d0.htm#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20Windows%20PE%20includes,cmd%20currently%20starts%20Wpeinit.exe.):

- winpeshl.ini in %windir%\System32 (this one starts the actual shell of the WinPE system)
- Autounattend.xml in the drive's root